# Hard Drive slowing to a crawl

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, sata

About a month or so ago I built a new PC for myself, I currently have an SSD that I had as a secondary drive in my previous PC as the main C:\ drive, a brand new 3TB Toshiba HDD as my E:\ drive and the main drive of my previous PC as F:\

The brand new 3TB Toshiba HDD has slown to a crawl on both read and write access. Currently I have 296GiB/2.72TiB used up, so masses of free space.

After running Crystal Disk Mark on the drive I got 1MB/s read and 0.8MB/s write speed.

Crystal Disk Info has given me this diagnostics info and says that the status of all drives is good.

-- Controller Map ----------------------------------------------------------

- Standard SATA AHCI Controller [ATA]

  - SAMSUNG HD103SI
- Standard SATA AHCI Controller [ATA]

  - TSSTcorp CDDVDW SH-222AB
  - SanDisk SDSSDHII480G
  - TOSHIBA DT01ACA300
- Microsoft Storage Spaces Controller [SCSI]

-- Disk List ---------------------------------------------------------------

1. SanDisk SDSSDHII480G : 480.1 GB [0/0/0, pd1] - sd
2. TOSHIBA DT01ACA300 : 3000.5 GB [1/0/0, pd1]
3. SAMSUNG HD103SI : 1000.2 GB [2/1/0, pd1]

...

---

### (2) TOSHIBA DT01ACA300

```
           Model : TOSHIBA DT01ACA300
        Firmware : MX6OABB0
   Serial Number : 46R4NWHAS
       Disk Size : 3000.5 GB (8.4/137.4/3000.5/3000.5)
     Buffer Size : Unknown
     Queue Depth : 32
    # of Sectors : 5860533168    
   Rotation Rate : 7200 RPM
       Interface : Serial ATA    
   Major Version : ATA8-ACS        
   Minor Version : ATA8-ACS version 4        
   Transfer Mode : SATA/600 | SATA/600      
  Power On Hours : 152 hours       
  Power On Count : 39 count
     Temperature : 32 C (89 F)       
   Health Status : Good
        Features : S.M.A.R.T., APM, 48bit LBA, NCQ
       APM Level : 0000h [OFF]
       AAM Level : ----
    Drive Letter : E:
```

I am running Windows 10, my PSU is 630W, so that shouldn't be an issue. Any ideas as to why it's running so slowly and if I can do anything about it?

**Update**:
This seems to be intermittent, I tried to open a game on that drive about an hour ago and it hung before it had even gone full-screen or loaded anything, I checked the hard drive with CrystalDiskMark and it didn't even start the test after several minutes. I restarted my PC and it loaded the game almost instantly.

Comment: Verify the disk and CPU activity in the resource monitor.  I suspect something is probably overloading your machine, or otherwise there could be a hardware issue.

Comment: Have you tried checking Windows Resource Monitor to see if something else is saturating the hard drive?

Comment: You probably have to monitor your processes to see how much resources each one is consuming. Disregard any attempts to modify your hardware to give your better throughput and utilization of your available resources.

Comment: That sounds like PIO mode. Your copy/paste says "SATA/600 transfer mode," but this sounds like canned info. Check the DMA mode for the controller that the drive is plugged into using device manager.

Comment: For a drive that large, what is the RPM?

Comment: This morning I unplugged the SATA and power cable from the 1TB old drive, then booted up and tested the 3TB new drive and the speed had gone up to 60MB/s, I turned the PC off, plugged the old drive in again and repeated the test, still 60MB/s, so it seems OK for now, but I don't know if I should put that down as the "answer"

Comment: @Kaizerwolf the drive is 7200RPM

Comment: @Frank I can't figure out where to find the DMA mode setting in device manager in Windows 10, all the articles in Google are for other versions of Windows where there's an "Advanced" tab on the properties menu for the SATA controller (there isn't one on my machine, "Advanced" tab just isn't there)

Comment: @Steve Check the BIOS setting as well. Made sure that there isn't a fixed setting in the bios. But there should be an advanced tab. http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/check-your-transfer-mode-to-boost-computer-speed/

Comment: There is no advanced tab, I've double checked now:

Standard SATA AHCI Controller Properties
General Driver Details Events Resources

Comment: Also, I've updated the question to say that this problem is intermittent

Comment: I would boot using a live Linux CD, and use that to diagnose the problem (it is often difficult to tell if the problem is the OS or the hardware).